# Xcode no matching private key found

Tags: ios

I have an app which was distributed from another Mac, what do I need from the other Mac to be able to archive my app for upload, and which changes do I need in the Xcode paths to make all work. Thanks and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use someone's certificate, you have to obtain also private key associated with this certificat. In Key Chain of other Mac, you do a right click to the certificate (verify if it's associated with a private key) then choose 'Export'. You can add password to protect this .p12 file.

Then, you import this .p12 to your Mac.

But, why do you have to publish your app from your Mac but not from another Mac?

Comment: Before it was always published from his Mac, now he has no time and I have to do it from mine, I'm very confused right now and don't know what I do need on my mac from his and which paths I should change in xcode..

Comment: or is there a simple way to add a new certificate from my own mac?

Comment: Yes, you can use your own certificate. The step are: join apple programme (ask the guy to invite you to the team), create a certificate request signing then upload to Apple Member Center,  download this certificate and import to your Mac. Once you have access to APple Member Center, take a step to create new Certificate in this link: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateCreate.action

Comment: Attention, you can have only 2 distribution account. 1 is for distribute your applications, others is for backup in case other certicate expires. However, you can use both of them to distribute. But it's not recommended. So the best solution is use his certificate and do as my answer.

Comment: what do I have to change in the project settings in xcode? after I installed the new certificate in keychain, I mean which paths in Code Signing Identitiy(Debug, Release,Distribution) and Provisioning Profile(Debug, Release, Distribution)

Comment: You have to verify : bundle Id, change provisioning profile to match this bundle Id, change Code signing to the right one. Take a look at this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Comment: one problem is that the "App Store and Ad Hoc" is grayed out..whats the problem there?

Comment: It's normal. Your team has taken all of 2 distribution certificates.

Comment: so every account has only 2 certificates? when I delete the previous one, does it affect the app's which are in app-store?

Comment: Yes, do not delete or invoke certificates that have application in App-Store. As I said, 1 distribution certificate is for production, other is spare. One Apple Member enrolled has maxi 2 distribution certificates.